# FIDO2 on Android using Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, fido-u2f

We have an android app using Xamarin and webview. Our customers use the app to connect to their own server and would like to use FIDO2 passwordless sign-on; they currently use username and password.

Is there a solution for this out there? Where would one seek an answer for this problem?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/fido/android/native-apps

Comment: We need the target to be dynamic, as we don't own the domains.